# Group Orbits of this space under O(3)

Tags: matrices, group-theory, group-actions

Consider the vector space:
$$
\mathbb{V} = \{ \ A \in M_{3 \times 3}(\mathbb{R}) \ | \ A^{T} = A \mathrm{\ and\ }\mathrm{Tr}(A) = 0 \}
$$

As well as the Lie Group:
$$
O(3) = \{ \ A \in M_{3 \times 3}(\mathbb{R}) \ | \ A^{T}A = A A^{T} = \mathbb{I} \}
$$

Define the group action $\Phi : O(3) \times \mathbb{V} \to \mathbb{V}$ as $\Phi(A,X)= \Phi_{A}(X) = AXA^{T}$. I am to determine the group orbit$s$ of this action.

The way I am understanding this, is that I am to examine the structure of the set
$$
S := \{ \ \Phi_{A}(X) \in M_{3\times 3}(\mathbb{R}) \ | \ A \in O(3), X \in \mathbb{V} \ \}
$$

I know that symmetric matrices are orthogonally diagonalizable, which means that I can write $X = P D P^{T}$ for any $X \in \mathbb{V}$ (where $P \in O(3)$ and $D$ is diagonal and traceless).

This tells me that $\Phi_{A}(X) = AXA^{T} = APDP^{T}A^{T} = \Phi_{AP}(D)$, where $AP$ is just another matrix in $O(3)$. This tells me:
$$
S = \{ \ \Phi_{A}(D) \in M_{3\times 3}(\mathbb{R}) \ | \ A \in O(3), D = \mathrm{diag}(a,b,c) \mathrm{\ with\ }a+b+c=0 \ \}
$$

So the orbits of the whole vector space are exactly the orbits of the diagonal matrices in this subspace.

Can I narrow this down further?